# Can I get emacs to display a grid?

Tags: overlays

The question is if there's anything like a "background display mode" or maybe a package that once installed would allow a background grid to be displayed in the editor window. The Eclipse IDE for e.g. manages to display thin dotted lines to mark indentation, though I'm specifically asking for a grid. It might help keep code tidy.

Comment: There is no such animal, sorry.  There was a recent discussion on Reddit about creating a built-in visible fill-column indicator, and I have been working on creating horizontal and vertical lines using multiple fake cursors in conjunction with feature requests 22873 (multiple fake cursors) and 17684 (crosshairs that track the cursor position, and a visible fill-column indicator), but they are only proof concepts for the Emacs development team to consider.  Here is the Reddit link:  https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/anwqk6/native_fillcolumnindication/?ref=share&ref_source=link

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The cross-hairs looks good, is there any chance this would become a real Emacs feature?

Comment: The programmers on the Emacs development team have been kind enough to help me out when I get stuck while working on aspects of feature requests 22873 / 17684; and, there has been some discussion regarding whether Emacs should have multiple fake cursors as a built-in feature.  The crosshairs and visible fill column are drawn/erased using the same mechanism as multiple fake cursors.  I am uncertain whether Eli, John, RMS, etc. will ever decide to include any of those features.  The next draft patch (proof concept) should be ready in a week or so.  You may be interested in `vline.el` (overlays).